# Flask unit test can't connect to sqlite database when running tests

Tags: python, sqlite, unit-testing, flask, python-unittest

I am trying to run my unit tests for my flask application however I can't seem to connect to the database I use for my actual application when I import my app here:

```
from main import app
```

giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py", line 35, in <module>
    main(argv=args, module=None, testRunner=unittestpy.TeamcityTestRunner, buffer=not JB_DISABLE_BUFFERING)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/main.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/main.py", line 147, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/main.py", line 159, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 220, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/abbaslawal/Desktop/honours-project/tests/test_main.py", line 16, in <module>
    from main import app
  File "/Users/abbaslawal/Desktop/honours-project/main.py", line 65, in <module>
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Database/database.db', check_same_thread=False)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

The only way I can actually get the error to go away is to change the file path to the database in the application I want to test but I don't want to do this every time I want to run unit tests.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using a relative path in your `main.py`, your test application cannot find the file.
If you use an absolute path instead of a relative one, it should work regardless where your script is executed from.

Relative:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('Database/database.db', check_same_thread=False)
```

Absolute:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('/Users/abbaslawal/Desktop/honours-project/Database/database.db', check_same_thread=False)
```